# Failed trying to run app (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, xml

Hey guys i'm new to coding, i'm trying to run my app on android studio but everytime I do I get these errors

> What went wrong:
> A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' (type 'ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest').
> File 'F:\Android Studio Code\Latest Build\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\out\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'mainMergedManifest' does not exist.

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: File 'F:\Android Studio Code\Latest Build\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\out\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'mainMergedManifest' does not exist.

> Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction

> Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: F:\Android Studio Code\Latest Build\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\out

Bear in mind that it is showing no errors in the code.

Comment: Could you share your `build.gradle` and the `manifest` file for more clarity?]

Comment: This could be a problem with Build tools version or SDK version, you could be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You could be missing something.

Please check your `build.gradle` file for the set `compileSdkVersion` and the `targetSdkVersion`. Ensure that those SDKs are downloaded and installed and that you are testing with a device matching the minimum requirements you have defined.

E.g You could have specified a minimum SDK of 30 and maybe the emulator or other device you are using to test is SDK 28 i.e., lower than your minimum requirements.